# Update JSON object using JMESPath

Tags: jmespath

Can JMESPath be used to update the JSON object? A new attribute needs to be added to `people.data` as `"field1": "value1"`

```json
{
    "people": [
        {
            "age": 20,
            "other": "foo.aaa",
            "name": "Bob",
            "data":{
                "field":"value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this very special case, but JMESPath is not really the best tool to do this, [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) could possibly be a better suited alternative.

From what one can read in their respective site:

- *[jmespath](/questions/tagged/jmespath) is a query language for JSON. You can extract and transform elements from a JSON document. <sup>[reference](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#jmespath-tutorial)</sup>*
- while *[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor. <sup>[reference](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)</sup>*

So clearly, if you are looking for a JSON processor, you will probably be best served by [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

---

This said, there is a [`merge` function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#merge) that you can use to achieve this.
The caveat in the proposed solution here is that, since `people` is an array, it will add the key/value pair `"field1": "value1"` to **each element** of that array.

Given the query:

```
{
  "people": people[].merge(
    @, {
      "data": merge(
        data, {"field1": 'field1'}
      )
    }
  )
}
```

On your example JSON, you will get

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "age": 20,
      "other": "foo.aaa",
      "name": "Bob",
      "data": {
        "field": "value",
        "field1": "field1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```